# Setting the contents of a TextView in android

Tags: java, android

I'm very new to Java/Android, and I'm playing around with a simple app. I'm stuck with getting a TextView to display something. I've looked at a whole bunch of questions and feel like I'm doing exactly what is suggested but the setText is still not working properly.

The code I'm using is;

```
TextView wounding=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.wound_prob);
wounding.setText("hello");
```

This seems to be the same as I've seen suggested.

The error I am getting is that `setText()` cannot be resolved.

Any help is greatly apprecitated.

Comment: what error your getting >?

Comment: Have you added the import "import android.widget.TextView;" ?

Comment: Post what error you are getting?

Comment: The error is Cannot resolve symbol 'setText' and the widget has been imported.

Comment: Is it in onCreate method?

Comment: It is now, per another suggestion. Hadn't realised the importance of that. It's eliminated the error but still doesn't display anything in the textView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have done is possibly written your code soon after your class declaration where you can declare data members(also called global variables) of the class. You cannot access them or do any computation on them. Hence your first line doesn't show any compilation error but as soon as you access in 2nd line it does.

Please write your line of code inside your methods in your class file and not outside. try writing these in your `onCreate` method and see

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);// name of your layout
      TextView wounding=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.wound_prob);
      wounding.setText("hello");
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much. That seems to have eliminated the error but doesn't actually display anything in the textView. Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the height width of your textview. Can you add the code of your xml as well

Comment: You missed `setContentView ();`.

Comment: Ah, I thought that was understood by default and was just trying to explain where the code should go. But yeah Thanks @BirendraSingh for pointing it out.

Comment: Many thanks, that's working perfectly. Not to try and solve the next problem myself!